# How to list and edit html of all web part in sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I am new in sharepoint and I have to do a very simple modification in all web part. We have lots of web part containing very simple html. The html only contain a link and an image.

Web developers had put full links to pages and images and it cause some problems. I want to scan all of the web parts html and replace full links by relative links.

Is it possible ? We have tons of pages and links. Doing it manually will take 2 weeks!!!

Thanks!

EDIT #2:
Now the question is: Is it possible to list  all aspx files in my website?
I know how to access the web parts content with a url :

```
using (SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(
                "ca/Pages/Home.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared))
        {
            foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart wp in manager.WebParts)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(wp.Title);
                if (wp.GetType().Equals(typeof(Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart)))
                {
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart thisWebPart = wp as Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ContentEditorWebPart;

                    System.Console.WriteLine(thisWebPart.Content.InnerText );
                    System.Console.WriteLine(thisWebPart.Content.InnerXml);
                }

            }
        }
```

EDIT #1:
As requested their is an example:

I want to remove "http://www.mywebsite.com" from all shared webparts with code like this:

```
<A title="" href="http://www.mywebsite.com/Pages/Career.aspx" target=""><IMG style="BORDER-RIGHT: 0px solid; BORDER-TOP: 0px solid; BORDER-LEFT: 0px solid; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px solid" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/images/Career.jpg" border=0></A>
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the replacement you want to do. The link before and after modification.

Comment: what type of web part are you using a custom webpart or content editor webpart or something else

Comment: @Ashutosh Singh: content editor webpart

Answer (score 1):

In content editor web part the content is stored under   content tag

```
<Content xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ContentEditor"><![CDATA[<p>test document test document</p>]]></Content>
```

what i can suggest here is to open the site in sharepoint desginer and use the find and replace option for all pages

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got what's required exactly. What about writing a program that do that? Detect the links by regex and replace them.

Comment: It's exactly what I want to do. Its even simple then regex: I just need to remove the http://www.mywebsite.com But I don't know if its possible to iterate all of the webparts and modify the html code. I just know the manual "edit html code" button

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually change the content in Sharepoint, it could be difficult to do this in code.  Every webpart works differently, so there's no standard solution for all web parts.  For example, a CQWP can pull data from various lists, so the way to make the change for that webpart would be to change the data in the lists it pulls from.  Other webparts might pull data from SQL Server, Reports, have IFrames in them, etc.  Some webparts might even have the URLs hardcoded in a custom DLL, which you could only change by modifying the solution/feature that the DLL is a part of and redeploying the updated version.

However, an alternate solution is to write a Response Filter, which will take the output of Sharepoint and dynamically do a find/replace every single time a page is requested from Sharepoint.  See http://aspnetresources.com/articles/HttpFilters for more information on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Two parts to this, the first is to loop through all web part pages in your site - quite a few examples out there so not going to muddy things by repeating that here.

The second part is to update the Content property and save - seem like this is the missing part of your puzzle for [updating the Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) programatically](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2009/02/i-found-to-be-bit-tricky-to-update.html) so :-

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;

private void updateContentEditor(SPWeb web, string pageUrl)
{
    using (SPLimitedWebPartManager manager =
           web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(pageUrl, PersonalizationScope.Shared))
    {
        foreach (WebPart wp in manager.WebParts)
        {
            if (wp.GetType() == typeof(ContentEditorWebPart))
            {
                ContentEditorWebPart cewp = wp as ContentEditorWebPart;
                cewp.Content.InnerXml;

                // See http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2009/02/i-found-to-be-bit-tricky-to-update.html
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlElement xmlElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("MyElement");

                // Do you change logic here
                xmlElement.InnerText =
                   contentEditor.Content.InnerText.Replace(BEFORE, AFTER);

                // Save changes
                contentEditor.Content = xmlElement;
                manager.SaveChanges(cewp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```